# What does the question "What are the very serious diseases caused by mosquitoes?" need, subject or complement?

Tags: exam-questions, subjects, complements

> What are the very serious diseases caused by mosquitoes?

I'd like to know whether the word "What" is used as a subject in the question above . Thanks.

Comment: Do you not understand the question's meaning, or are you interested in quibbling about which is the subject and which is the complement in an "are" predication?

Comment: Where should I put the answer to this question, in place of "What" or behind the verb "are"?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

> **The very serious diseases caused by mosquitoes are** malaria, dengue, chikungunya, etc.

Comment: Dear Joao Arruda, can I rewrite it as "Malaria, dengue, chikungunya, etc. are very serious diseases caused by mosquitoes"?

Comment: Yes, in this case the order doesn't matter, it all goes with the focus you want to set in this sentence. If the focus is "warn that there are many serious diseases caused by mosquitoes", then my sentence is better fitted. But if the focus is "warn **which** are the serious diseases caused by mosquitoes" then your sentence is more appropriate.

Comment: The focus of the sentence fits always better in the beginning of the sentence, in the cases in which the order of subject/predicate doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

"The very serious diseases" is the subject.

I don't think *what* in this case is a subject complement, because it's not a modifier.

The verb *to be* doesn't take an object, but what follows it is a type of grammar called a *predicate* that gives additional information about the subject - either a predicate word (noun, etc.) or phrase.  (A few other verbs can take predicates, such as *look*, *appear*, etc.)

I *think* that *what* here is technically a *predicate noun* or *predicate nominative* (a pronoun standing for one), since it renames the subject in a sense.  [Reference](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/predicate-noun.html).